# How do I select only nodes with a certain CSS class ? D3/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I want to select only nodes with a "hidden" class applied to it. I have other shapes that have the "hidden" class applied but I only need to select the nodes.

I thought this may work :

```
var nodesVisible = inner.selectAll(".node").selectAll(".hidden")
            .classed("hidden", false);
```

In the HTML it has : `class: "node hidden"`

So I have also tried

```
var nodesVisible = inner.selectAll("node hidden")
```

But this doesn't select the nodes with the hidden class applied

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes need to prepended with a dot:

```
var nodesVisible = inner.selectAll(".node.hidden")
```

Select all uses css selectors. Here is the doc about css selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: bloody hell haha i tried : inner.selectAll(".node .hidden"), so i mistakenly put a space in between. Cheers man will accept the answer when it allows me to :)

Comment: You're not the only one. I made a css selector with 200 chars and it didn't work :') Took me an hour to realize it was just one space to much

Answer (score 1):

you can do it only using pure javascript like this

HTML

```
<div id="c" class="hidden otherclass">  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var div=c //get the element by id

if(div.className.indexOf('hidden')>-1&&
   div.className.indexOf('otherclass')>-1){

alert("yes the element has a hidden and otherclass classes")
// do other stuff
}
```

**UPDATE**

i added >-1 in condition

Comment: i accepted @vincent beltman' answer as I'm working with D3 and his was the one I was looking for. However I am sure I will use your answer in the future, so thank you :) Vote up ++